# Should email address be stored after logout?

Tags: security, language-agnostic, passwords, remember-me

I've written an add-on for a web application that inserts a "Remember Me" checkbox into login forms. One of my users expressed surprise that they are not remembered after logging out! Clearly someone who has logged out should stay logged out, and despite a specific request I will not fill the password field as that means storing the password in clear text.

My question is should the email address/username be pre-filled for a login form if a user has previously marked the "Remember Me" box?
Obviously if done on a public computer that would be effectively broadcasting their personal details to the next stranger who used that computer, but a user shouldn't use the "Remember Me" option on public computers anyway.

What are the security considerations of doing this? Do users expect some of their details to be remembered after logging out?

**Edit:** It occurs to me that browsers all have a feature to remember form values and login details anyway, perhaps making this unnecessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Remember me" is not the same thing as "keep me signed in."

Many banking sites use "remember me" to save the username (but not the session) even after the user has logged out (ING Direct and Citizens Bank are a couple of examples). They usually hide part of the name for security purposes.

To make things clear for your users, you probably want to change the wording to "stay signed in" or something similar.

Comment: I think you have picked out the crux of the matter: Semantics. Different people expect different behaviours from these vague terms we use. It would be bad practice to behave unexpectedly but we can't always predict what that means to everyone. I think I shall have to avoid the issue and make it optional for whomever configures the site. From asking here and elsewhere it appears the majority would prefer having that convenience. Personally I find it suspicious and would agree with @Troy Hunt, "[it's not fine] when the user has specifically signed out".

Comment: Moreover, I like the banks' examples of hiding the exact username and only indicating that the person is recognised. If more people expected that behaviour they may be more reluctant about giving their full details to those 'update your account' type phishing sites.

Answer (score 3):

You should absolutely *not* pre-populate the email / login if someone has used the "remember me" feature. Keep in mind that this feature - also often called "keep me signed in" - is designed to persist the logged-in state across sessions. It's a usability feature to save the user from re-authenticating every time they visit the site.

It's *not* a means of persisting any part of the login credentials after explicitly signing out. Yes, the browser can remember form field values such as the login name but most security guidance explicitly recommends disabling this (refer to [OWASP Top 10 for .NET developers part 3: Broken authentication and session management](http://www.troyhunt.com/2010/07/owasp-top-10-for-net-developers-part-3.html)).

In terms of security systems, I certainly don't think there's any user expectation to pre-populate this data simply because the vast majority of websites don't operate in this fashion. Lowering the barrier to entry is fine if it's done with explicit consent, but not when the user has specifically signed out or ended their session and not when the behaviour is inconsistent with what they'd expect.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming their email address is the being used as their user identifier, this is the behavior I expect and frequently see from many applications that I don't expect high levels of security from.

A more secure implementation it to store an encrypted identifier and only ask for the password when the user tries to login.  This is the behavior I see and expect from sites that hold my financial sites.  Ensuring the browser doesn't remember the password field is important for such sites.

It is good practice to place a warning about not using "Remember me" on public computers next to the check box.

Comment: Thank you. This is the sort of opinion I wanted to hear.